# if and elif satements in a while loop (in a function) is not changing a variable declared in the function

Tags: python, variables

```
def hello():
    while True:
        global opened, filepath
        command = input("save or open: ")
        opened = False
        filepath = "Empty"
    
        if command == "save":
            if opened:
                print(f"yes you opened a file {filepath}")
            else:
                print(f"no you didn't open a file {filepath} {opened}")
        elif command == "open":
            filepath = "/home/pi/Desktop/testing.txt"
            opened = True
            print(f"opened {filepath} {opened}")
        else:
            print("typo")

hello()
```

I want to change the opened and the filepath variable as i've tried to demonstrate but am failing to do so, i need the filepath to change when i want it to, but it doesn't. It just dosen't regester and change both of the variables and prints out Empty and Fasle respectively.
btw this is my output:

```
save or open: open
opened /home/pi/Desktop/testing True
save or open: save
no you didn't open a file Empty False
```

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `opened = True`, but you will overwrite it in the next loop iteration with `opened = False`.

You will need to initialize variables before the `while` loop.

Also, there is no need to use `global` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hello():
    opened = False #moved these
    filepath = "Empty"
    while True:
        command = input("save or open: ")
    
        if command == "save":
            if opened:
                print(f"yes you opened a file {filepath}")
            else:
                print(f"no you didn't open a file {filepath} {opened}")
        elif command == "open":
            filepath = "/home/pi/Desktop/testing"
            opened = True
            print(f"opened {filepath} {opened}")
        else:
            print("typo")

hello()
```

result:

```
save or open: open
opened /home/pi/Desktop/testing True
save or open: save
yes you opened a file /home/pi/Desktop/testing
```

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer, or just another splattering of brain spill? If the former, please edit to clarify what you changed and why.